# If the last 3 digits of a decimal number "looks like" binary, then the first 3 binary digits are the same. Why?

Tags: math, binary

So I randomly stumbled upon something that got me by surprise.
I noticed that if a base 10 number ends 3 digits of 1 or 0 then the first digits of the binary value will be that pattern. 
**I am not a genius by any means in this field**

Examples by random:

```
56101 = 1101101100100 101
789456111 = 101111000011100010010011101 111
789456000 = 101111000011100010010010000 000
101 = 1100 101
111 = 1101 111
110 = 1101 110
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Why does it happen from 1 - 3 digits only? Does it actually happen to other cases constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the binary representation of (decimal numbers) 1, 10, 100, which (in binary) are 1, 1010, 1100100. The binary value of 1000 ends with three zeros.

So, if you image the last three decimal digits of a particular number as being `abc` (each of which will be either nought or one), then the last three binary digits of your binary representation will also be `(a * 100 + b * 010 + c * 001)`, which gives just `abc` (there being no carries).

When you try to extend this process to the last four or more digits of your decimal number, you get more likelihood of collisions between the bits. For example, the bit-pattern of (decimal) 10 is 1010, where its highest-order bit (bit 3) collides with the representation of (decimal) 1000. So, the argument above breaks down because you'll now get carries (from bit-3 upwards) when you add together the binary representations of your decimal digits.

Comment: Ah that is a good way to explain it. I understand it now. Even if it has no real significance, it is still pretty interesting.